# Cannot locate resource

Tags: c#, wpf

I don't know exactly if it is a bug but i am getting all the time runtime IOException error saying Cannot locate resource.

I am loading some images in my app (c#, WPF) in canvas background depends on database state.
The problem is, that i cannot load LAST (alphabeting sorted) file. I have for example 15 images in folder. I can load 14 first without problems. But the last one all the time throw exception.

I am 100% sure, that i HAVE the image in the folder (see !image-printscreen below).
And how i wrote. 14 first i can load without any problem, only the last one throw exception.

Is it a bug in WPF-c# or am I doing something wrong?

code what is throwing exception:

```
canvas_status.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(BaseUriHelper.GetBaseUri(this), @"Images\" + statusName + ".png")));

canvas_name.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(BaseUriHelper.GetBaseUri(this), @"Images\" + statusName + bulheadName + ".png")));
```

error:

```
IOException was unhalded
Cannot locate resource 'view/images/panel_uzavreno_d.png'.
```

image (for higher resolution click on image right mouse button and click on SHOW IMAGE or something like that):

[image: printscreen]

Comment: thats not the problem, that is "newer" version (i found on internet, that this will solve the problem, but it doesnt). When i have it without the "view" folder, it doesnt work as well and it throw same exception :(

Comment: @piggy please don't use screenshots from services other than Imgur because they tend to get deleted or blocked which will render your question useless for future visitors with the same problem.

Comment: ah ok :]. sorry, it is right now on imgur (thank you for edit)

Comment: Are all your images set to Resource and Do not copy?

Comment: it is added throught -> add existing item (not in resources but in solution explorer)

Comment: Try a clean rebuild and see if the error sticks around

Comment: In may case (xaml resource referenced from another xaml file not at root) ONLY a relative path would work: "./Subdir/resource.xaml"

Answer (score 38):

I've had a similar issue: IOException, cannot locate a png resource which indeed existed in the assembly.

I found the solution by **explicitly specifying the assembly name**, even though the caller was in the same assembly as the resource.

Here's how it looks with a Pack URI syntax:

```
pack://application:,,,/MyAssemblyName;component/MyResourcesFolder/MyImage.png
```

(For more about Pack URIs see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))

**Edit:** One more thing I had to do after specifying the assembly name was to **Clean** the project. The problem returns after build but was resolved after cleaning the intermediate products.  This is definitely a bug in Visual Studio.

Comment: It seems that Expression Blend 4's designer also has a similar bug.  I was trying to load a Style file (located in the same assembly) at design-time to solve another one of Blend's bugs/features (where it does not find resources from App.xaml) and found that your method of explicitly including the assembly name was the only way to solve its design-time "resource not found" exception. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, had this issue in a WPF desktop application in .NET 4.5, this one fixed it.

Comment: Thank you! Cleaning the project was the key to get the Pack URI to work. Good that I read your entire post.

Comment: Yep, same issue. VS2013 though

Comment: Explicitly specifying the assembly name was the trick. Nothing else in google land helped.

Comment: FYI--I was using an ico file in UWP and it blew up with this error. Until I changed the file name to all lower case.  Seems that when the file is being loaded on startup, somewhere in the back end the file name it's looking for gets changed to all lower case.  The easy way out is to just make the file lower case to match what it will look for.

Comment: 12 years later and clean is still the solution. Amazing. Upvoted.

Answer (score 26):

You need to set the build action of the image to the type 'Resource'.

Right-mouse click on the file >> Properties >> set 'Build Action' to 'Resource'

Comment: It seems the image also needs to be added to the Resource file.