# Is there a way to make custom shader effect properties animatable inside Blend?

Tags: wpf, animation, shader, expression-blend

Custom shader properties cannot be seen on the Blend UI such as in picture below :

[image]

By looking at source of DropShadowEffect (which is part of WPF), animatable properties have been defined like this :

```
DropShadowEffect.ShadowDepthProperty = Animatable.RegisterProperty(...);
```

Unfortunately, **Animatable.RegisterProperty** method is **internal** what forbids doing so, the only way working is to manually code a storyboard.

Is there a way or a library that would allow to have this ability back for custom shaders ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the origin of the issue : the URI of the shader was incomplete !

It should be like this :

```
var pixelShader = new PixelShader();
pixelShader.UriSource = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/YourAssembly;component/YourEffect.ps", UriKind.Absolute);
```

**Subtlety : do not forget the @**

Reference :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13112241/361899

Properties are back now :)

[image]

Note : all previous stuff on question (Animatable) is not needed anymore.